# Syntax error when creating the trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, centos

I am getting syntax error in creating the following trigger:

```
create trigger x.generate_responsibility 
before insert on x.organization_applications_b 
for each row 
begin

    call x.resp_auto_generate(new.org_id,new.application_code);

end;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precede this command with:

```
delimiter //
```

and follow with

```
delimiter ;
```

so you can use the semi-colon as part of your trigger source while defining your trigger, then make the semi colon the usual command delimiter after you're done.

The whole thing should look like this:

```
delimiter //
create trigger x.generate_responsibility 
before insert on x.organization_applications_b 
for each row 
begin
    call x.resp_auto_generate(new.org_id,new.application_code);
end; //
delimiter ;
```